# Java Concurrency: How can I tell which Future belongs to which Callable during processing?

Tags: java, concurrency, future, executorservice, callable

I have a collection of Callables and a ExecutorService.  When I invokeAll, I get back a list of Future objects.  How can I tell which Future object mapped to which Callable before the Future completes?  I can tell afterwards because the

Code:

```
 ExecutorService es = .....;

 Collection<Callables> uniqueCallables = .....;  // each Callable is unique!

 List<Future> futures = es.invokeAll(uniqueCallables);

 // TODO--find unique Future A which is the future for Callable A!
```

Comment: Just out of interest, why would you need such information?

Comment: The futures may (will) complete at different times, perhaps minutes apart.  I distinguish different types of tasks by ID.  Someone else may want to run the same task (by ID) bt not realize it's already in process. 

invokeAll was a bad choice--ended up going with submit because invokeAll doesn't return until all the tasks complete/time out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on [Java reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29), `invokeAll(uniqueCallables)` preserves the order in `List<Future>` as the order produced by `uniqueCallables.iterator()`:

> **Returns**: 
>   A list of Futures representing the tasks, in the same
>   sequential order as produced by the iterator for the given task list,
>   each of which has completed.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you simply need to be able to lookup the original callable from a Future. If you weren't using invokeAll, you could decorate the Executor wrapping the submit() to create a ContextualFuture that keeps a reference to the original callable.

```
/*pseudo example*/
class ContextualFuture<RETURN> implements Future<RETURN> {
   private Callable<RETURN> callable;
   private Future<RETURN> wrappedFuture;
   public ContextualFuture(Callable<RETURN> callable, Future<RETURN> future){
       this.callable = callable;
       this.future = future;
   }
   // implemented/wrapped methods 
}

class ContextualThreadPool {
   private ExecutorService wrappedExecutor;
   public <T> ContextualFuture<T> submit(Callable<T> task){
       Future<T> f = wrappedExecutor.submit(task);
       return new ContextualFuture<T>(task, f);
   }
}
```